# How do I render to multiple 3d targets in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I have some legacy DX11 code that renders to multiple 3d render targets. Destination target is passed via `SV_TARGETxx` and the slice is set via `SV_RenderTargetArrayIndex` in GS. Is there any way to do the same in Vulkan?

My plan is to create individual view for each slice of each 3d target and pass them all together as attachments to a single frame buffer, then in GS I can have something like `gl_Layer = sliceNo + targetOffsets[xx]`. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

In Vulkan, the GS SV_RenderTargetArrayIndex is called `Layer` in SPIR-V or `gl_Layer` in GLSL. It behaves the same as in D3D. You create one view per 3D target, and attach that to the framebuffer. The `Layer` output from the GS will say which layer (of all the targets) the output primitive is drawn to.

In Vulkan there's no "true" 3D framebuffer attachments, in the sense that after projection to screen space coordinates everything exists in a 2D plane. So attachment image views can have 2D_ARRAY dimensionality, but not 3D. The  [Image and image view parameter compatibility requirements](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#resources-image-views-compatibility) table says that given a 3D image, you can create a `2D_ARRAY` image view with `layerCount >= 1`. Note that you have to create the image with the `VK_IMAGE_CREATE_2D_ARRAY_COMPATIBLE_BIT` flag.

So if you want to have *N* 3D render target images:

- Create your *N* 3D images, with the `VK_IMAGE_CREATE_2D_ARRAY_COMPATIBLE_BIT` flag.
- Create one image view for each image, with `VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D_ARRAY` and `layerCount` equal to the number of slices you want to be able to render to.
- Create a `VkRenderPass` with one `VkAttachmentDescription` per 3D render target, plus whatever others you need for depth/stencil, resolve target, etc.
- Create a `VkFrameBuffer` based on that `VkRenderPass`, and pass your image views in the `VkFrameBufferCreateInfo::pAttachments` array. Set `VkFramebufferCreateInfo::layerCount` to the number of layers/slices you want to be able to render to.

[Edit: Below paragraph can be ignored based on first comment. Leaving it for transparency.]

I'm confused what you're trying to do with `SV_Target[n]`. In both D3D and Vulkan, if you've got multiple render targets / color attachments, the fragment shader will write to all of them -- if your fragment shader doesn't provide a value for a bound target, the value written is undefined. So `SV_Target[n]` is used to tell which shader output variables go to which target, but they don't let you write to some without writing to others. Vulkan works similarly, using output variables `gl_FragData[n]` in GLSL.

Comment: No, I am not trying to write to some without writing to the others, I write to all of them. My question is actually about the proper way to attach several 3d targets to the same framebuffer and same pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about having 1 draw call rendered from multiple points of view (but otherwise using the same pipeline) then you want [VK_KHR_multiview](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_multiview.html).  This is an extension in Vulkan 1.0, but core in 1.1.

There's an example of it's usage [here](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/multiview/multiview.cpp) and the corresponding shader functionality is [here](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/data/shaders/multiview/multiview.vert).  It functions similar to what you seem to describe.  You attach multiple images from a texture array to a single framebuffer ("rendertarget" in D3D) and then in the vertex shader you can determine which layer you're rendering to via the `gl_ViewIndex` variable.  There's no need for a geometry shader with this approach.